# Check if File Exists in Directory by using a Text File and Wildcard

Tags: bash, grep

If you have a text file with lines

```
abc
123
def
hij
```

And you have a directory of files called

```
abc.txt
tgr.txt
lot.txt
hij.txt
```

And you want to get the files in the directory that match a line in the text file and move those files in that directory to a sub-directory, what is the best way to do this in bash?  The sub-directory, in this example, would have the files:

```
abc.txt
hij.txt
```

What I'm thinking is to do something that says: if that string* exists (with a wildcard) in the directory as a filename, move that file to a subdirectory.

I understand that I could potentially use a combination of the **find** or the **grep** commands, but I'm honestly stuck as to where to proceed from there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat text.txt | while read line; 
do 
    find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$line*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} ./target
done
```

Pipe your text file into a loop and search for each line in the current directory. If you find something pipe into `xargs` (if you find multiple files) and move each file into your target directory.

Comment: Maybe get rid of the [useless use of `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: yes, you could also write `done < text.txt` but I think the version with `cat` is easier to understand for beginners